# flutter : Text on image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to write text with transparent color on image. like this.

[image]

I want to write text over the image but I am not able to do it properly.

This is my code.

I want to write text over the image but I am not able to do it properly.
And I also want transparent color for text.
Please help me.

```
import 'package:card_example/color_filters.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static final String title = 'Card Example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

        title: title,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange),
        home: MainPage(title: title),
      );
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MainPage({
    @required this.title,
  });

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),

        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          children: [
         Card(

        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [

            Ink.image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                'https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/photo/2018/04/22/c19486c2-4e5b-48c4-82af-c6d0eebb7bd2/Main.jpg',
              ),
              colorFilter: ColorFilters.greyscale,
              child: InkWell(

                onTap: () {},
              ),
              height: 240,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Text(
              'Sachin Tendulkar',

              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ],

        ),
      )
          ],
        ),
      );

}}
```

I want to write text over the image but I am not able to do it properly.
And I also want transparent color for text.
Please help me.

If want to use for that container and I use decoration for image text widget for text then how to make exact that thing like is in image.

Comment: If you're using a Stack, your Text should have an Align widget to be forced bottom. If not, you can use the BoxDecoration from a Container to create the same effect.

Comment: do you want splassEffect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider `splashColor`, there are multiple ways to handle this:

**using Ink.image() inside Stack** will not provide `circular borderRadius`. Check [this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30193) is still open.

[image]

```
 ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sachin Tendulkar',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Ink.image(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/photo/2018/04/22/c19486c2-4e5b-48c4-82af-c6d0eebb7bd2/Main.jpg',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      );
```

**1: Using GridTile**

```
Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: GridTile(
              child: Image.network(
                'https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/photo/2018/04/22/c19486c2-4e5b-48c4-82af-c6d0eebb7bd2/Main.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              footer: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
                child: Text(
                  'Sachin Tendulkar',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

**2: Using decoration of Container**

```
 InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                'https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/photo/2018/04/22/c19486c2-4e5b-48c4-82af-c6d0eebb7bd2/Main.jpg',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Text(
              'Sachin Tendulkar',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: play around with font and opacity of text container.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `bottomCenter` to `alignment`

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //Here
  children: [
    Ink.image(
      image: NetworkImage(
        'https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/3661dd45c31a4ff23941855a7e4cedbbf6973643/assets/start_remove-79a4598a05a77ca999df1dcb434160994b6fde2c3e9101984fb1be0f16d0a74e.png',
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      height: 240,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Text(
      'Sachin Tendulkar',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 24,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How do you get circular border ?